# JNI GetMethodID Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <method>

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to read From java.io.Reader to a char buffer allocated in C using posix_memalign.

In my java code

```
  public class LowerCaseTokenizer
{

 public native void Initialize(Reader input) throws IOException;
 public static String example = "XY&Z Corporation - xyz@example.com";

  public LowerCaseTokenizer(Reader input) throws IOException {

   Initialize(input);
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.loadLibrary("LowerCaseTokenizer");

        LowerCaseTokenizer sample = new LowerCaseTokenizer(new StringReader(example));}

}
```

For the C++ code, I did the following.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_LowerCaseTokenizer_Initialize(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj1, jobject obj2){

jclass input_class = env->GetObjectClass(obj2);
  jmethodID jread_method = env->GetMethodID(input_class, "read", "(C[II)I" );

  print_object_class_name(env, obj2);

}
```

The problem is that I get

```
Calling class is: java.io.StringReader // print_object_class_name(env, obj2); 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: read
```

The purpose of getting this method is I want to read from a reader to a buffer that is allocated in C++ (I am taking into account UTF16 (16bit) per char problem while allocating the buffer).

Due to this bug, I haven't check if reading to the buffer implementation is gonna work. But some insights won't hurt.

```
do{
  numCharsRead  = env->CallIntMethod(obj2, jread_method ,source_ptr ,off , len);

  }while(numCharsRead != -1);
```

Comment: How did you generate the cpp header?

Comment: haven't packaged it, it resides in LowerCaseTokenizer.java file which I run and compile and run straight away for faster testing.

Comment: Wrong signature string. Don't guess at JNI method signatures. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the read function is not "(C[II)I".

I wrote in c not cpp. But I think you just need to replace the signature of the read method.

```
/*
* Class:     com_neohope_jni_test_LowerCaseTokenizer
* Method:    Initialize
* Signature: (Ljava/io/Reader;)V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_neohope_jni_test_LowerCaseTokenizer_Initialize
(JNIEnv *env, jobject caller, jobject reader)
{
    getJniClassName(env, caller);
    getJniClassName(env, reader);

    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, reader);
    if (clazz == NULL)return;

    jmethodID midRead01 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "read", "()I");
    jmethodID midRead02 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "read", "([C)I");
    jmethodID midRead03 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "read", "([CII)I");

    //do your job here
    if (midRead01 == NULL)return;
    jint ret = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, reader, midRead01);
    printf("%l", ret);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` means that Java is unable to find a method with a name and signature matching what you have requested. Your request is:

```
env->GetMethodID(input_class, "read", "(C[II)I" );
```

You can get the correct type signature using javap

```
> javap -s -classpath rt.jar java/io/StringReader
  ...
  public int read(char[], int, int) throws java.io.IOException;
    Signature: ([CII)I
```

But you are using `(C[II)I` instead of `([CII)I` --- your `[` is misplaced.

Comment: Thanks that's very valuable info.

Comment: I like it that you mentioned javap